# Phonegap sends notifications inside ajax request

Tags: ajax, notifications, phonegap

I am trying to get notification on android/ios. I have an ajax request inside a setinterval function, and I want it to notify me, when the ajax request turns true.

Can anyone ever try to do this or did this before?

I already try to use plugin push, but actually I don't know, how it works.

Comment: I imagine this will be straightforward for someone to help. Can you post the code of what you've tried? And what output you're expecting?

Comment: I don't really understand your post. You should learn to write comprehensible questions. [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/291370/1783163) would be a good start for that, it is easy to follow but it is a *big* help for others, trying to understand your questions.